# How to get X and Y coordinates of an EC Point in Rust?

Tags: rust, cryptography

I'm trying to extract X and Y coordinates from a EcKeyopenssl::pkey::Private key in Rust.
I have managed to convert it to a point and bytes, but I don't know how to get the coordinates.

```
pub fn exportpubkey(key: &EcKey<openssl::pkey::Private>) -> (){
    let group: EcGroup = EcGroup::from_curve_name(Nid::SECP256K1).unwrap();
    let mut ctx: BigNumContext = openssl::bn::BigNumContext::new().unwrap(); 
    let bytes = key.public_key().to_bytes(&group,openssl::ec::PointConversionForm::COMPRESSED, &mut ctx).unwrap();
    println!("{}", display_bytes(&bytes));
}
```

Comment: Where does your EcKey type come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to look at the method [affine_coordinates](https://docs.rs/openssl/latest/openssl/ec/struct.EcPointRef.html#method.affine_coordinates)

```rust
use openssl::{bn::*, ec::*, nid::Nid};

pub fn print_pub_key(key: &EcKey<openssl::pkey::Private>) -> () {
    let group: EcGroup = EcGroup::from_curve_name(Nid::SECP256K1).unwrap();
    let mut ctx: BigNumContext = BigNumContext::new().unwrap();
    let public_key = key.public_key();
    let mut x = BigNum::new().unwrap();
    let mut y = BigNum::new().unwrap();
    public_key
        .affine_coordinates_gfp(group.as_ref(), &mut x, &mut y, &mut ctx)
        .expect("extract coords");

    println!("{}, {}", x, y);
}

fn main() {
    let group: EcGroup = EcGroup::from_curve_name(Nid::SECP256K1).unwrap();
    let key = EcKey::generate(&group).unwrap();
    print_pub_key(&key);
}
```

Note that `affine_coordinates_gfp` and `affine_coordinates_gf2m` seem to give back the same coordinate in your chosen group.

Answer (score -1):

**Watch out!**

For anyone who come to this post and looking for a method to get the x,y cordinates from the **public key**, the method provided in the answer of @Cyrill is not for you. If you with to know the G and other parameters, you may also vist https://neuromancer.sk/std/nist/P-224.

I have validated with my colleague, **the x,y coordinate pair from the code is the **G**enerator's**. You are free to double check by replacing the private key to different keys without changing anything else, the x,y will always be the same.

```
fn insecure_keygen() {
    let private_key_b64 = "YOUR BASE64 ENCODED PRIVATE KEY";
    let private_key_bytes = base64::decode(private_key_b64).expect("Failed to decode base64");
    let group = EcGroup::from_curve_name(Nid::SECP224R1).expect("Failed to create EC group");
    let private_key_bn = openssl::bn::BigNum::from_slice(&private_key_bytes).expect("Failed to create BigNum");
    let private_key = EcKey::from_private_components(&group, &private_key_bn, &group.generator()).expect("Failed to create EC key");
    let mut ctx: BigNumContext = BigNumContext::new().unwrap();
    let public_key = private_key.public_key();
    let mut x = BigNum::new().unwrap();
    let mut y = BigNum::new().unwrap();
    public_key
        .affine_coordinates_gfp(group.as_ref(), &mut x, &mut y, &mut ctx)
        .expect("extract coords");

    println!("{}, {}", x, y);
}
```

[image]